# Ngx-charts: draw non continuous line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ngx-charts

Is there a native way with ngx-charts to draw non-continuous line chart ? I'm using the normal "line chart" but cannot find a way to achieve this (to those who wonder: no I cannot simply put "0" as value).

Same question for vertical stacked bar chart (in this case, setting the value "0" is visually acceptable but still not correct).

It seems this option exists in d3 (cf [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090)).

Thanks